# Is there a way to bind to the ExceptionManagerModule similar to RCTExceptionManager?

Tags: android, exception, react-native

In React Native you can bind a delegate to `RCTExceptionManager` on the iOS side to catch errors and handle them yourself ([like this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1418#issuecomment-106892463)).

However, looking into Android the `ExceptionManagerModule` only takes in a `DevSupportManager` and seems to be instantiated inside the `CoreModulesPackage`. I tried instantiating the module a second time using a `DevSupportManager` subclass, but you cannot instantiate the same module more than once.

Is there any way to add a custom error handler on the native Android side?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to override core modules if the `getName()` return the same as the core module and if `canOverrideExistingModule()` returns true.

You can see an example of that on the library that I did to support Crashlytics https://github.com/aoriani/ReactNative-StackTracer/blob/master/rnstacktracer/src/main/java/com/github/aoriani/rnstacktracer/StackTraceManagerModule.java